# where can i find view html pages in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I went through the project structure of magento ,but couldn't find the view pages.
I am zend MVC developer and new to magento.
where can i find the router page and html pages for view?

Answer (score 0):

Magento 1 makes use of `themes` for frontend views, and layouts.  Magento provides a set of `base` template files, that provide the default information and layout for pages. These can be found within `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/`.  `Theme fallback` allows for you to create and configure a separate theme folder, i.e. `/app/design/frontend/mypackage/mytheme/template/` and only override the files you require.